# Azure: How to connect two VMs to one single Public IP address

Tags: azure, router, portforwarding

I have one public IP

and two VMs

port 80 map to VM1

port 25 map to VM2

Sadly I can't find anything like a NAT router in Azure :*(

Comment: load balancer would work, you dont really need nating

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by creating the VMs in the same availability set and deploy a Internet facing load balancer, then add [NAT rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/lb/inbound-nat-rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-lb-inbound-nat-rule-create).

By doing the above VMs use the same public IP address and different ports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It says that I have to re-create my VM in order to move this into the same Availability Set :(. I can't destroy my existing VM. Is there any other option?

Comment: you can just move the vm https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/move-azure-vms-avset-azone

Comment: You cannot move VMs into an availiblity set you do have to recreate them. That link is for availiblit zones. However you do not need the VMs to be in the same availiblity set if you use a standard load balancer